# Java simplyfying a function

Tags: java

I have written a function that checks if a string contains certain words but am not happy with the way the code looks

SO currently i have

```
private String url  = "validator=http://url.com;useraccount=sf4cdamloci;licence=39I8934U401;addedon=343443334;serial=7QW0-5TU8-YN9P-G4FZ;limit=123;days=10"

private String musthave ="validator,useraccount,licence,addedon,serial,limit,days"
```

So i wanted to check that the url contains the must have words in the string. That eg url must have validator, useraccount, licence.....

SO i have tried the following

```
 Boolean has_validator = false;
 Boolean has_licence = false;
   .....//others with has_ prefix
String[] split_url = url.split(";")
for(String key_item : split_url){
   String[] splitteditem = key_item.split("=");

    if (splitteditem[0].equalsIgnoreCase("validator")){
         has_validator = true;
     }

    if (splitteditem[0].equalsIgnoreCase("useraccount")){
         has_useraccount = true;
     }

       ....others as well
}
```

Then later i can easily check

```
if(has_useraccount && has_...)
```

The above solution works buts its not scalable as whenever i include a new must have ill have to edit my function.

Is there a better way to achieve this. Am still new to java. I have checked on regex but still i can figure our on how to achieve this.

How do i proceed

Comment: Use a `Set<String>` for your `mustHave`. Then `mustHave.stream().allMatch(uri::contains)` will return `true` only if every item in the set is in the string `uri`

Comment: Is the logic around this dependent upon specific validations being present; are you relying on the boolean values elsewhere such that a single boolean result of the search isn't sufficient?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a String to represent a set of Strings. Use... a Set of String: `Set<String>`. Or at least an array of strings.

Then just use a loop. If any of the word in the set isn't contain in the text, you can immediately return false. If you have never returned false in the loop, then all the words are contained in the text, and you can return true.

Pseudo code:

```
 for each word in the set
     if the word is not in the text, return false
 end for
 return true
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `Collection` of must-have strings, then you can do something simple like:

`mustHave.stream().allMatch(url::contains)`

My example isn't doing a case-insensitive check, but you get the idea.